# Kivy application doesn't work correctly if I use pynput global hotkeys

Tags: python, kivy, pynput

I am trying to create an application which is hidden by default and windows is shows when key combination is pressed.

My code:

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from pynput import keyboard


class MyApp(App):
    def open_window(self):
        print(f"Key pressed...")
        self.root_window.show()

    def build(self):
        return Label(text="Hello")

    def on_start(self):
        self.root_window.hide()

        with keyboard.GlobalHotKeys({"<ctrl>+<alt>+h": self.open_window}) as h:
            h.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

When I run the app everything looks fine but no label is shown and I am unable to close the app in single click of close button. After multiple attempts of closing the window I get python not responding error.

Thanks.

[image]
[image]

Comment: This is happening to me too, except my app does not respond when I open it at the beginning. . .

Answer (score 2):

use this

```
from kivy.core.window import Window, Keyboard
from kivy.logger import Logger
```

or

```
class MyApp(App):
def build(self):
    Window.bind(on_key_down=self._keydown)
    Window.bind(on_key_up=self._keyup)
    return Autoclicker()

def _keydown(self, window, key, scancode, codepoint, modifiers):
    print('keydown:')
    print('\tkey:',key)
    print('\tscancode:', scancode)
    print('\tcodepoint:', codepoint)
    print('\tmodifiers:', modifiers)
def _keyup(self, window, key, scancode):
    print('keyup:')
    print('\tkey:',key)
    print('\tscancode:', scancode)
    # call anything
    if key == 287:
        print("yessssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss")
```

Comment: This requires window focus. I want to trigger hotkey without window focus. Hence, I used pynput.